# Deciding whether the event $\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n(\omega) \leq c\}, c \in \mathbb{R}$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am wondering whether my reasoning is correct, that the (to be said) event belongs to the tail sigma-algebra. Namely, let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be given and consider the event $E = \{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n(\omega) \leq c\}$, where $S_n(\omega) = \sum_{i = 1}^n A_i(\omega)$ for real valued r.v. $A_1,A_2,\dots$ in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ We'd like to decide whether $E$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra $\mathscr{F}_\infty = \bigcap_{k=1} \sigma((A_i)_{i > k})$. Suppose that it is known that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_n$ is a $\mathscr{F}$-measurable function, and $\lim \sup S_n$ and $\lim \inf S_n$ are tail-sigma-measurable.

Then, if we first consider the event $T_1 = \{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n(\omega) \text{ converges}\}$, we see that it is the complement of the event

$T_2 = \{\bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{Q}}\{\lim \sup S_n > a\} \cap \{\lim \inf S_n < a\}\}$, i.e. the lim sup and the lim inf of $S_n$ always differ. Here both the events $\{\lim \sup S_n > a\}$ and $\{\lim \inf S_n < a\}$ belong to the tail sigma-algebra by measurability of lim sup/inf. Therefore, the whole event $T_2$ is a countable union of intersections and complements of the elements of the tail sigma-algebra, so that $T_2$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra, so that $T_1$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra as its complement.

If we then replace each of the events $E_1^a = \{\lim \sup S_n > a\}$ and $E_2^a = \{\lim \inf S_n < a\}$ by $G_1^a = \{c \geq \lim \sup S_n > a\}$ and $G_2^a = \{\lim \inf S_n < a \land \lim \inf S_n \geq c\}$, isn't it true that both $G_1^a$ and $G_2^a$ are also in the tail sigma-algebra (again, by the measurability of lim sup/inf), so that the original

**EDIT**
event $E$ can be represented as a union of modified $T_1'$ and $T_2'$, where $T_1' = \left\{\omega \in \Omega: \text{the sequence }S_n \text{converges to a limit less than or equal to }c\right\}$ and
$T_2' = \left\{\omega \in \Omega: \text{the sequence }S_n \text{diverges to negative infinity or oscillates with values less than or equal to }c\right\}$

so that $E = T_1' \cup T_2'$, $T_1' = (\{\bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{Q}}G_1^a \cap G_2^a\})^c$, $T_2' = T_1^c$,

so that (finally) the original event $E$ belongs to the tail sigma-algebra?

Comment: The proof looks good. For a quick way to decide: the event is not affected if the first finitely many $A_n$'s are deleted so that it must be a member of the tail.

Comment: I don't think $\limsup S_n$ is tail-measurable, what is tail-measurable is $\limsup A_n.$ In fact, notice that every member of the $S_n$ depends on all the variables $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ (regardless of the index $n$), so it seems very unlikely that $\limsup S_n$ is tail-measurable.

Comment: Your particular event is not in the tail $\sigma$-algebra as the value of $\lim_nS_n$ depends not only on tails but also on the first values of the summands. The event $\{S_n\,\text{converges}\}$ does belong to the $\sigma$-tail.

Comment: @OliverDiaz My thought process for this problem was the following: As $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are arbitrary, some of the, for example, converging sums might converge to values greater than $c$ in the event $\left\{\omega \in \Omega: \text{the sequence }S_n \text{converges to a limit less than or equal to }c\right\}$. If this is the case, then those particular sums $S_n$ are discarded.

But apparently this is not a valid way to think about the tail sigma-algebra?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Is the reason why the original event $E$ is not in the tail sigma-algebra that, for example for $A_1(\omega) = 2c, A_k(\omega) = 0, k > 1$ converges to $2c$?